# Binding Combobox to xml file problem

Tags: wpf, xml, mvvm, binding, combobox

this is my xml

```
<Courses>

  <Course Name="Computerarchitectuur" />
  <Course Name="Frans" />
  <Course Name="Programmeren" />

</Courses>
```

in my xaml i call this by:

```
 <XmlDataProvider x:Key="blabla"
                Source="C:\Users\Ruben\Desktop\Stage 26-04\stage_TFW\stage_TFW\NewWPFVragenBeheer\Data\Courses.xml"
                XPath="/Courses/Course"
           />



<ComboBox DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource blabla}}"  ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=@Name}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="128,67,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" SelectionChanged="comboBox1_SelectionChanged" />
```

My problem is, it only shows the first element, namely "Computerarchitectuur. DOes anyone know what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="blabla" Source="C:\Users\Ruben\Desktop\Stage 26-04\stage_TFW\stage_TFW\NewWPFVragenBeheer\Data\Courses.xml" XPath="Courses/Course" />
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource blabla}}" DisplayMemberPath="@Name" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="128,67,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" SelectionChanged="comboBox1_SelectionChanged" />
```