# XML passed to me, to bind to a grid in C#

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, datagrid

I have a program, that does a call to another program. This program returns me some XML. Is there a way to bind this XML from memory to a datagrid or grid?  The examples I have found all show how to bind xml from a file, but my is not on disk, it is in memory, called from another program.  What would my syntax be? I only have a variable, with the XML as a blob. How can I get this into a datagrid?

```
if (Customer.ToString() != null)
{
    var XmlIn = InvoiceQueryXml(Customer.ToString());
    var XmlToParse = queries.Query(sessionId, "ARSQRY", XmlIn);
}
```

So my XML will be in the XmlToParse variable.... This is what I need to get into my grid.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855601/binding-combobox-to-xml-file-problem
or Assigned Data-context.

Comment: That still uses XML from a source file... I only have XML in memory and have no clue how to display these nodes on a grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get string from your byte array and then use it like xml. For examle:

```
        //buff is your byte array
        string xmlStr = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buff);
        //now xmlStr contains your xml data and you can do something with it. 
        //For example load to xmlDocument
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xmlStr);
```

Comment: Thank you, will try this out quick and let you know of my results